# Why is my rope weird-looking?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I am trying to make a 2 coil steel rope with the Array and curve modifier.

[image]

[image]

What is happening at the start of this rope? I'm trying to twist it but it's twisting the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Merge* value is too high, some vertices are merging with some other ones that they sould not, bring this value back a low value, like 0.01:

[image]